# App is unable to write to the registry, even though the user has administrative privileges

Tags: c#, .net, registry, .net-2.0, uac

I am using Visual Studio 2010, and I'm writing a program that needs to set (and read) new registry values under `HKLM\Software\myapp`

The program is .NET 2.0-based and as for now it runs on Windows 7 64-bit. Here is my ocde:

```
RegistryKey softwareKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software", true);
RegistryKey MyKey = softwareKey.CreateSubKey("MyApp");
RegistryKey  = MyKey.CreateSubKey("MyKey");
selfPlacingWindowKey.SetValue("instaldateperson", datestr + usrname);
```

The problem I have when running Visual Studio 2010, is that it will run the app but logged on as me, I am a user and member of local admin group.. however I cannot create the key (despite I am part of local admin group, who have rights to do so). Neither do I know how to do it as a logon as (but its also not what I want since then I would put Adminuser and password inside the code, and I already am admin ?? so why ??)

If this isn't possible at all, are there options for creating registry keys?

Somehow add them to the project or so ??.. I am a bit confused here.

Comment: The question was simple about HKLM, the application deals with setting hardware settings and was an installer part.

I ended up putting the registry parts into the deployment part of the machines, and thus i could run vbscripts in Windows post installation (just before it launches user login). This solved for me the need to do this.
As this is a good working workaround instead of a solution i keep it this way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just because you're running as Administrator (or using an account with administrative privileges) does not mean that those administrative privileges are always in effect. This is a security measure, preventing malware from exploiting users who foolishly use their computer all the time with administrative privileges.

To wield your administrative privileges, you need to *elevate* the process. There are two ways to do this:

1. Use a manifest that indicates your application requires administrative privileges, and thus demand elevation at startup.

   This means your application will *always* run elevated and should only be used when your application needs this. The Windows Registry Editor (RegEdit), for example, does this, because there's little you can do there without administrative privileges.

   Find information about how to accomplish this [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx), or in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383288/how-can-i-embed-an-application-manifest-into-an-application-using-vs2008). Basically, you just want to add the following line to your manifest:

   ```
   <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" />
   ```
2. If you only need administrative privileges for certain tasks (i.e., saving a particular setting to the registry) and the rest of your application does not require it, you should launch a new elevated process to do this. There is no way to temporarily elevate the current process, so you actually need to spin off a new process.

   The advantage of this method is that your application does not have to run with administrative privileges all the time (which increases security), and that users who do not have administrative privileges will still be able to run your app to do everything else (i.e., everything but the one or two tasks that do require elevation).

   You spin off a separate process that contains only the logic needed to write to the registry using the `Process` class and request elevation for this process using the `runas` verb. For more information, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programatically). I have also written [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5508000/366904) that provides a complete description how to accomplish this from C#, including sample code.

Of course, as other answers have mentioned, it is more likely that the design of your application is incorrect. The whole logic of the Windows security model is that regular applications to not *require* administrative privileges. They don't need to write to the registry or do other things that could potentially compromise the machine. If you need to persist settings, might I suggest two other possible approaches:

1. Recognizing that Windows is indeed a multi-user operating system and writing your settings only for the current user. This makes good sense anyway because different users often have different settings and preferences. Instead of the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` branch of the registry (which requires administrative privileges to access), you would want to use `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. Change your first line of code to:

   ```
    RegistryKey softwareKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software", true);
   ```
2. Skipping all of the hassle and complication of writing to the registry altogether by using logic built into .NET to persist your application's settings. Start reading [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26369/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-user-settings-for-a-net-application), or on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4s6c3a0.aspx) to learn how to do that. I'd say that this is by far your best option. Don't write complicated code yourself to do something that the framework you use already has built-in support for doing with ease.

Comment: Well the point is that during installation i want to set some keys
And those keys should not be part of HKCU but be part of HKLM ..

Comment: Great answer. It's worth mentioning though I also had to set the Platform target setting to "Any CPU" instead of "x86" to be able to write to HKLM programmatically. Took hours to figure that one out... o_O

Answer (score 3):

The design of your application is probably wrong. Standard desktop apps are not supposed to write to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. Because of UAC, you need to have administrator rights, and be running in an elevated process in order to be able to write to `HKLM`.

If your application does need to make changes to `HKLM` then consider doing so at installation time because the installer will be run elevated.

If a desktop application does need to write to `HKLM` then it should consider separating those parts of the application that need to run elevated into a separate process. Otherwise the users are going to be very fed up with having to go through a UAC dialog in order to run your application. Even if they aren't using the part of the application that writes to `HKLM`. And if you force the entire app to require elevation then standard users can never run it at all.

Comment: ... how would it be possible to do some post installation stuff in the code of my app ? which would trigger at installation time from within routines inside my app ?

Comment: I don't fully understand that question. If it triggers at installation time, then it's not post-installation.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can't create the key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE while running Visual Studio is because Visual Studio isn't running as an elevated process.

For end-users the manifest of the application needs to indicate that full Administrator privileges are required. Here is the documentation on [embedding a manifest for UAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756929.aspx)

If the registry key doesn't need to be global on the machine consider writing to HKEY_CURRENT_USER instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should to give writable permission adding true value after your key in the method.

```
Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(@"YOURKEY", true);
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"YOURKEY", true);
```

Also you need elevated permissions to do that, then you can create a .manifest file and setting the level in `requireAdministrator` like that:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

---

NOTE:
In your code:

```
RegistryKey softwareKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software", true);
RegistryKey MyKey = softwareKey.CreateSubKey("MyApp");
RegistryKey  = MyKey.CreateSubKey("MyKey");
selfPlacingWindowKey.SetValue("instaldateperson", datestr + usrname);
```

Check if the object label si correct, you are using the labels `softwareKey` and `MyKey` to create an object but to set the value you are using another label `selfPlacingWindowKey`.

Answer (score 0):

Resuming. Create a .manifest file in your project. Give it the same name as the executable. "name_of_executable.exe.manifest" Finally change or create the tag for:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level = "requireAdministrator" uiAccess = "false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers mentioned that you need to specify in the manifest that you require administrator permissions to use `HKLM`

You can create a manifest by;

1. Right click on your project,
2. Going to Add New
3. Click On General
4. Click on Application Manifest File
5. Click Add
6. Open your manifest file and find and un-comment the `requireAdministrator` line

The more nuanced thing that may be tripping you up is having `Prefer 32bit` ticked in your project settings.

This will mean that the Registry can't get the access mask it requires and it will fail silently without an inner exception because the error handler needs the same access mask so it can't be exploited.

You should avoid storing things in this part of the registry unless you absolutely need to persist settings across users, The registry also shouldn't be used to store passwords or other sensitive information as you can NOT reliably control access even with ACLs.