# Access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, wpf

For my WPF application, I have to create folders with images files for eg: C:\Pearl\Src\TEMP. Later when those files are not needed, I am deleting the folders programmatically. But I get "Access to the path ' '  is denied". I also tried to assign access rights to the temporary folders created but not of much use.

```
using System.IO;

var activeDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

var dInfo = Directory.GetParent(Path.GetDirectoryName(activeDir);

var dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(@"ATSDEV\ABCD", FileSystemRights.DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles, AccessControlType.Allow));

dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity); // Set the new access settings.

var ImageDir = Path.Combine(dInfo.ToString(), "TEMP");

System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(ImageDir, dSecurity);
```

Comment: Can you post the exact line that throw the exception ?  
Seems like the error is your way to get the pathname

Comment: Are you sure you have not got any handles (files) still open?

Comment: It's called **[UAC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210575/does-windows-7-have-the-same-problem-as-vista/5210642#5210642)**. You aren't supposed to be writing to that directory at all. Luckily, there are alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have windows xp. Still I tried the above appdata folder. Its still the same. The path now is C:\Documents and settings\UserName\Application Data\672011115302AM

Comment: LoSciamano: Here is the code where its throwing error: File.Delete(p_folderpath); where p_folderpath is C:\Documents and Settings\UserName\Application Data\672011115302AM

Comment: this sounds weird but XP has a weak user access controll. Maybe you can use Temp directory as [this reply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268326/access-to-the-path-is-denied/6268604#6268604) suggest

Answer (score 8):

In Vista+, you shouldn't ever write to the installation folders or parent folders of the executing process.  Instead, you should consider writing to a subdirectory in the User's AppData folder, as this will be more appropriate, and not cause permission issues.

You can get the appropriate folder via [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx)([Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have windows xp. Still I tried the above appdata folder. Its still the same. The path now is C:\Documents and settings\UserName\Application Data\672011115302AM

Comment: @user296623: Yes, and in XP, it's preferred to do that too.  In Vista+, though, you'll have even more issues...

Comment: @user296623: If you can't delete the folder, it probably means something is holding a handle to a file open inside of it...

Answer (score 2):

I also had the problem, hence me stumbling on this post. I added the following line of code before and after a Copy / Delete.

**Delete**

```
File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
File.Delete(file);
```

**Copy**

```
File.Copy(file, dest, true);
File.SetAttributes(dest, FileAttributes.Normal);
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can use `Path.GetTempPath()` to get path to temp directory and create your temp data in there.

good thing about using Temp is that if you got forget/fail to clean it up, when drive space is slow, system can help you to clean it up.