# C++: how to convert ％USERPROFILE% path to file path (should work on Windows XP and later)

Tags: c++, windows

How to convert ％USERPROFILE% path to file path in C++? It should work on Windows XP and later versions.
I need it because when I'm trying to launch .jar file with `CreateProcessW` method using javaw.exe, the file is not found.

Comment: possible duplicate of [expand file names that have environment variables in their path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902681/expand-file-names-that-have-environment-variables-in-their-path)

Comment: Possible duplicate - but no good answer for me. There is nothing about `SHGetFolderPathW` method.

Comment: Folders returned by `SHGetFolderPath` have nothing to do with environment variables. All the less with expanding them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function that expands environment variables. For instance `getenv`, or on Windows you could choose to use `GetEnvironmentVariable`.

However, the right way to find the user profile directory is to use the Windows API for it. If you need to support XP then you need to use the CSIDL for that folder: [`CSIDL_PROFILE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494.aspx). Use [`SHGetSpecialFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762204.aspx) to read out the path associated with a particular CSIDL value.

This is how to get the user profile directory, although I must admit to struggling to understand how that would help you launch javaw.exe.

**Update**

In the comments you indicate that you actually want the temporary directory. Use `GetTempPath` to obtain that.

Comment: I have to get full path to TEMP directory. I have read registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Environment` `TEMP`, but the value contains %USERPROFILE%, and that creates the problem to javaw.exe - it does not know what is %USERPROFILE%.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827496/how-to-properly-use-userprofile-inside-code

Comment: If you want the users temp directory path then `GetTempPath` may be helpful.

Comment: Currently I'm using value from registry, but %USERPROFILE% is replaced with `SHGetFolderPathW` using `CSIDL_PROFILE` flag. Maybe `GetTempPath` is even better. Thanks for help indeed :)

Comment: Well, what you are doing now is plain wrong. You have to use GetTempPath.