# Store db file in shared directories 

Tags: c#, windows-7, installation, sql-server-2008-express

when i am install my application to client machine which have window 7 then give me error that db file don't have read or write permission.

how can i give permission to that file ?

[i already read other solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/fafe818f-8aa3-46cd-bb69-55e540e7a62e/) that i should store the db file in shared directories which have read write permission for every user.

but i want to store my database file into my program files folder and want to give permission to that file so it can also work in window 7 .

thanks

***EDITED :--***

as now all of you suggesting to save the db files in shared folder so my new question is now

how to store .mdf file in shared folder when making setup in c#. what changes should i make in app config file. currently its storing program files in my application folder where my application don't have read write permission .

currently my mdf file is on root and my app config file have this line of code :

```
<add name="HotelReservationSystem.Properties.Settings.HotelReservationDBConnectionString"
      connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\HotelReservationDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: There is no good reason to ever store information inside of the Program Files folder. That's why it's been made much more difficult in Windows Vista and later. The security risks make it completely unjustifiable. What, exactly, do you think is wrong with using a shared directory like everyone else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Windows 7 have the same problem as Vista?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210575/does-windows-7-have-the-same-problem-as-vista)

Comment: @CodyGray will you please suggest  any link what should i have to change in my code or making setup to store db file in shared directory and changes in app.config file

Comment: I have no idea how you're doing it now, so how should I tell you what to change? Wherever you specified the path, change it to a different one.

Comment: will u please come on chat so it will be easy for me to give u idea about all this .

Comment: No, I don't do chat. Update your question with the relevant information if you want people to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately after Windows XP this is NOT possible. In order for a user to write to anything in Program Files they need Administrator access. Not only do they need Administrator access but they also need UAC permission.

So you have to options

1. Place the database in a read/write folder like ApplicationData
2. Make your app run as admin UAC rights by adding the setting in app.manifest

Comment: have u any link which is related to making a setup in vs2010 with mdf file for window xp window7

Comment: or how can i place my mdf file in those folder ? as i just add these files in my setup project by adding the files option

Comment: Nothing unfortunate. Unless you are a programmer thinking following specs is stupid - this was changed way before XP. Dumbo programmer ignroed it. There is a specific folder for that.

Comment: @TomTom I only programmed AFTER XP so I only assumed you could do this (and no I do not test my apps under XP, because you should really stop using XP in this lifetime). I just been accustom to placing things is UAC safe places

Comment: @rahularyansharma I use INNO installer or Installshield and I set up the database path in there

Comment: @MyKuLLSKI hello sir i installed the install shield wizard for vs2010 but there is no option to set up the database path

Comment: @rahularyansharma I'm not sure what db you using but Google is your friend. You should mark this as an answer and ask a new question or search the web... http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isp_db.htm

Comment: Switch over to WIX and learn what you are doing there (windows installer is not a "i have no clue and click around" technology unless you want to get into serious trouble - some reading is warranted).