# What folder guarantees user has write access on windows?

Tags: windows, security

I need a folder guarantees the logged in user has write access to , currently I use roaming profile folder but the client doesn't want me to use that folder anymore, is there any other folder I can use or is there a list of folders I can chose from?

note: ideally I dont want to use the %temp%

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you using it for? Temporary files or persistent (permanent) files?

Comment: Do you mean you currently use the roaming profile folder or the roaming application data folder?  If the latter, why does the client not want you to use it?

Comment: All explained in my answer here: [Does Windows 7 have the same problem as Vista?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210575/does-windows-7-have-the-same-problem-as-vista)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [SHGetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA` if your app needs to run on pre-Vista systems, and [SHGetKnownFolderLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `FOLDERID_LocalAppData` if you're running only on Vista and later.

In either case, your application should create a folder under the returned location, and store your user-specific information in that folder.

Comment: This is 100% what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use the local (non-roaming) AppData folder.