# How to save RichTextBox text to a text resource file?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have created a text file named 'Notes' in the resources of my project and want to load/save the text of a `RichTextBox` to it. I tried using `MyProject.My.Resources.Notes` in the path. It doesn't show any error in the code window but when I run it, it shows an error.

Here's what I'm using to load the text:

```
RichTextBox1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(MyProject.My.Resources.Notes)
```

Here's what I'm using for saving it:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(MyProject.My.Resources.Notes, RichTextBox1.Text)
```

This is not a duplicate. I did not get an answer from the other question

Comment: Whilst saving i get these:

`FileNotFoundException was unhandled`

and

`A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write to a text file inside of the application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487006/how-to-write-to-a-text-file-inside-of-the-application)

Comment: If you have added a text file called "Notes" to your project's Resources (using the Resources tab of the project's properties page), you can read it like this `Dim myNotes As String = My.Resources.Notes`. However, you can't write to the resource. If you want to update it, you can write it somewhere else, or use `My.Settings` instead.

Comment: Is there any other way to store text inside the application itself without using `My.Settings` as they are notes and could be multi-lined.

Comment: Application resources are not a database.  So, no, you can't write to it at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a regular file which always works fine or a database?

Edit: maybe this helps?
www.dondraper.com/2011/01/easily-save-and-retrieve-application-and-user-settings-in-vb-net-or-c-apps/

Comment: I've never used databases so i guess i'll just use regular files. I wasnt using them because I want the software to be a standalone EXE file.

Comment: Check out the link I just added. Maybe it helps